# Python - Ping a specific IP that is input

Tags: python

I'm trying to ping a specific ip address that is input after the application is run. Here is my current code, but every time I input an IP it comes up with errors saying invalid syntax. I've searched other topics but they involve pinging a range of IP's at once. Thanks for your help.

```
def pingComputer():
import os
hostname = input("Enter the ip address: ")
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'is up!'
else:
    print hostname, 'is down!'
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct in this question?

Comment: You need to provide the exact error message

Comment: I don't think there is a -c parameter for ping but not quite sure

Comment: I get "`IndentationError`", but that's what I would expect.  `def pingComputer()` should indent the lines that are supposed to be in this function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code in question, but here is a closer to working version:

```
# put the imports here for better readability.
import os

def pingComputer():
    # you need to indent when you write code for a function
    # you also need to use raw_input in python 2.x because raw_input returns a string
    # where input tries to interpret the input.
    hostname = raw_input("Enter the ip address: ")
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

    if response == 0:
        print hostname, 'is up!'
    else:
        print hostname, 'is down!'

# you weren't calling your function,
# I added a standard main check which will call your function.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pingComputer()
```

There are a couple of useful resources you could look at for [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in python 2.X which will help you choose which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

convert hostname into string before ping

```
def pingComputer():

  import os
  hostname = input("Enter the ip address: ")
  response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + str(hostname))
  if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'is up!'
  else:
    print hostname, 'is down!'
```